# Nullability mismatch in simple assignment after switching to sound null safety

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I switched to sound null safety and started getting runtime error in a simple assignment, that should never happen with sound null safety:

```
final widgetOnPressed = widget.onPressed;
```

Error:

```
type '(LogData) => void' is not a subtype of type '((LogData?) => void)?'
```

I can repro it for Flutter versions `2.12.0-4.1.pre` and `2.13.0-0.0.pre.505`.

PR: https://github.com/flutter/devtools/pull/3971

Failing line: https://github.com/flutter/devtools/blob/9fc560ff2e6749459e2ca6a1dc00bf6fb16ed93b/packages/devtools_app/lib/src/shared/table.dart#L1184

To repro, start DevTools at this PR for macos, connect to an app and click the tab 'Logging'. DevTools will show red screen and error in console.

Is it dart bug or the app bug? If it is the app bug, how can I debug it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in your code.

You didn't say which kind of error you got - a compile-time error or a runtime error. I'm guessing runtime error. (Well, you did say to launch it in the debugger, so that is a good hint too.)

The line `final widgetOnPressed = widget.onPressed;` looks like it can't possibly fail. After all, the type of the local variable is inferred from the expression assigned to it, and the runtime value of that expression will surely be a subtype of the static type because the type system is sound!
Isn't it? ISN'T IT?

It's not, sorry. Dart 2's type system is *mostly* sound, even more so with null safety, but *class generics* is covariant, which can still be unsound. It's fairly hard to hit one of the cases where that unsoundness shows its ugly head, but *returning a function* where the *argument type* is the class's type variable is one.

Your state class extends `State<TableRow<T?>>`, so the `widget` getter returns a `TableRow<T?>`. The [`onPressed`](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/blob/9fc560ff2e6749459e2ca6a1dc00bf6fb16ed93b/packages/devtools_app/lib/src/shared/table.dart#L1071) of that type has type `ItemCallback<T?>?`, aka, `void Function(T?)?`.

You create a `_TableRowState<LogData>`, with its `widget` which has *static type* `TableRow<LogData?>`, but you *somehow* manage to pass it a `TableRow<LogData>` instead. That's fine. Class generics are covariant, so all is apparently fine at compile-time.

Then you do `final widgetOnPressed = widget.onPressed;`.
The static type of `widgetOnPressed` is `void Function(LogData?)` here.
The *actual runtime type* of `onPressed` is `void Function(LogData)` because it's from a `TableRow<LogData>`.

A `void Function(LogData)` is-not-a `void Function(LogData?)` because the former cannot be used in all places where the latter can (in particular, it can't be used in a place where it's called with `null`).

This assignment is potentially unsound, and actually unsound in this case. The compiler knows this and inserts an extra check to ensure that you don't assign a value to the variable which isn't actually valid. That check triggers and throws the error you see.

How do you avoid that?

Don't create a `TableRow<LogData>` where a `TableRow<LogData?>` is required.

Or type the variable as:

```dart
final ItemCallback<T>? widgetOnPressed = widget.onPressed;
```

(no `?` on the `T`).

Or rewrite everything to avoid returning a function with a covariant type parameter (from the class) occurring contra-variantly (as an argument type).

Which solution fits you depends on what you want to be able to do.

Comment: Thank you! Got it. I replaced T? with T in `class _TableRowState<T> extends State<TableRow<T?>>` and it solved the problem